How can I show homeomorphism about two specific topologies like ($\mathbb{R}, T_2$) and ($\mathbb{R}, T(2))$
Definition$T_2=\{U \subseteq \mathbb{R}: 2 \notin U \} \cup \{\mathbb{R} \}$ and definition $T(2)=\{U \subseteq \mathbb{R}: 2 \in U \} \cup \{\emptyset \}$ let it be given. How can i show that this two topological space are homeomorphic (or not homeomorphic) between them? Solutions that come to my mind is finding function that continuous, bijection and $f^{-1}$continuous but what will be the range of $f$? Could this be $f:(-\infty,2)\cup(2,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ? Or do we need to examine topological properties such as compactness? (Like one of them compact but not other)

Those are not topologies on $\mathbb{R}$.

Oh sorry If I fix it like this, I think the topology is provided. $T_2={U \subseteq \mathbb{R}: 2 \notin U } \cup {\mathbb{R} }$ and  $T(2)={U \subseteq \mathbb{R}: 2 \in U } \cup {\emptyset }$

Hint: Can you tell which one point sets are open in each of the topology?

$T_2$ is not a topology, because $\mathbb{R}\notin T_2$. I am assuming that you mean $T_2\cup\{\mathbb{R}\}$. The same goes for $T(2)$, it should be $T(2)\cup\{\emptyset\}$.
With that in mind, I don't think those two spaces are homeomorphic.
This is because any open cover with the topology $T_2$ is trivial (because the only open set that contains $2$ is $\mathbb{R}$), so that it is compact.
But for $T(2)$, the cover $$(-\infty,2],[2,3], [2,4],\ldots $$
admits no finite subcover, so that it is not compact.

Yes, as you think, I fixed the topologies. This idea helped a lot, thanks. Now I try to find relationships about Hausdorff spaces.
